# Solr error 500 on phrasequery search for text_general field

Tags: solr, phrase

getting query error on :

LNm:"PersonLastName III"

Response is:  "field \"LNm\" was indexed without position data; cannot run PhraseQuery'

Schema is:

```xml
<field name="LNm" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>

    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: Did you already see this? http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/quot-Indexed-without-position-data-quot-strange-exception-in-eDisMax-Solr-4-0beta-td4011220.html

Answer (score 17):

This is because you changed field_type from string to text_general and didn't do a clean index. So indexer doesn't have necessary position data. First empty your core using

```
/your_core_name/update?stream.body=<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>&commit=true
```

then index this core.

**Attention:** the update code above will delete all your data in core and this cannot be undone!

Comment: worked perfectly, just deleted & then added all documents again.

Comment: Second time i run into this answer. Second time it saved me some serious issue tracking. Can't upvote it twice though.

Comment: @jan Glad to hear that helped ;)

Comment: But why does the index have to be flushed? Would just re-adding documents not work?

Comment: @TimBezhashvyly Nope. This is the main point of the problem indeed. Because the analyzer changed, if you don't flush the index it will have two different type of index data. And this causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

I also got same error because of using copyfields in "PF" parameter of solr.
remove any copyfields from "PF" parameter ,It will work smoothly .

**My Solr Schema =>**
**copyField source="name" dest="sname"**

**My SolrConfig file=>**
attr_Cuisines^20 **sname^10** neighbourhood^5 subcats^10 tags^1 features^2

when I removed **"sname"** from **"PF"** parameter,it worked